# "scala.MatchError" is thrown when execute HQL via Spark

Tags: scala, hive, apache-spark

My spark is compiled via:

```
mvn -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.2 -Dhadoop.version=2.2.0 -Phive -Phive-thriftserver -DskipTests clean package
```

Then I try to write a demo for reading records from my Hive table. The following code works fine:

```
object HiveTest {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    // -- configuration --
    val hconf = new Configuration()
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("HiveTest")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
    val hqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)

    hqlContext.sql("show databases").collect().foreach(println)

    hqlContext.sql(
      """
        FROM logbase_db.logbase_2
        SELECT doc
        limit 10
      """.stripMargin).collect().foreach(println)
  }
}
```

But when I applying my UDF to HQL, it throws error:

```
scala.MatchError: interface java.util.Map (of class java.lang.Class)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveInspectors$class.javaClassToDataType(HiveInspectors.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSimpleUdf.javaClassToDataType(hiveUdfs.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSimpleUdf.dataType$lzycompute(hiveUdfs.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSimpleUdf.dataType(hiveUdfs.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Alias.toAttribute(namedExpressions.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.Project$$anonfun$output$1.apply(basicOperators.scala:25)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.Project$$anonfun$output$1.apply(basicOperators.scala:25)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.Project.output(basicOperators.scala:25)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.Limit.output(basicOperators.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.PhysicalOperation$$anonfun$unapply$1.apply(patterns.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.PhysicalOperation$$anonfun$unapply$1.apply(patterns.scala:61)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.PhysicalOperation$.unapply(patterns.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceStrategy$.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:34)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:58)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.sparkPlan$lzycompute(SQLContext.scala:418)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.sparkPlan(SQLContext.scala:416)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.executedPlan$lzycompute(SQLContext.scala:422)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.executedPlan(SQLContext.scala:422)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SchemaRDD.collect(SchemaRDD.scala:444)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:29)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:34)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:36)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:38)
    at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:40)
    at $iwC.<init>(<console>:42)
    at <init>(<console>:44)
    at .<init>(<console>:48)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:7)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:852)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1125)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:674)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:705)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:669)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:828)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:873)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:846)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:873)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:846)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:873)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:846)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:873)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:846)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:873)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:846)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:873)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:846)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:873)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:785)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.processLine$1(SparkILoop.scala:628)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.innerLoop$1(SparkILoop.scala:636)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.loop(SparkILoop.scala:641)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:968)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:916)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:916)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:916)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1011)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.launch(SparkSubmit.scala:358)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

My UDF:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.*;

public class RowToMap extends UDF implements Serializable {

    private static final char SEP = '^';
    private static final char KVSEP = '=';
    private static final String AVAILABLE = "available";

    // must exist
    private static final String PLT = "plt";
    private static final String CAID = "k";
    private static final String UUID = "uuid";
    private static final String SPID = "p";
    private static final String IP = "ip";
    private static final String TYPE = "tp";
    private static final String TIME = "ti";

    private static final List<String> MANDANTORY_FIELDS =
            Arrays.asList(new String[]{PLT, CAID, UUID, SPID, IP, TYPE, TIME});

    private static final String STABLE = "av";
    private static final String SDK = "kt";
    private static final String OS = "os";
    private static final String MD = "md";
    private static final String URL = "pr";
    private static final String IE = "e";
    private static final String APP= "pn";

    private static final List<String> OPTION_FIELDS = Arrays.asList(new String[]{STABLE, SDK, OS, MD,URL,IE,APP});

    public Map<String, String> evaluate(String s) {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        String[] arr = StringUtils.split(s, SEP);
        for(String str: arr)
        {
            int index = str.indexOf(KVSEP);
            if(index>0)
            {
                String k = str.substring(0,index);
                String v = str.substring(index+1);

                map.put(k, v);
            }
        }

        boolean badLog = true;
        for (String mandantoryField : MANDANTORY_FIELDS) {
            if (map.containsKey(mandantoryField)){
                if (map.get(mandantoryField).isEmpty()) {
                    badLog = false;
                    break;
                }               
            }else{
                badLog = false;
                break;
            }           
        }

        map.put(AVAILABLE, badLog ? "available" : "");

        // OPTION_FIELDS
        for (String optionField : OPTION_FIELDS) {
            if (! map.containsKey(optionField)){

                map.put(optionField, "");
            }              
        }


        return map;
    }
}
```

My Spark code:

```
object HiveTest {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    // -- configuration --
    val hconf = new Configuration()
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("HiveTest")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
    val hqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)

    hqlContext.sql("CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION row_to_map AS 'com.hide.diablo.mzhiveudf.RowToMap'")
    hqlContext.sql("set ca-meta=ALL")

    hqlContext.sql(
      """
        FROM logbase_db.logbase_2
        SELECT row_to_map(doc) AS row,dateid
        WHERE dateid >= 20140318 AND dateid <=20140318
        limit 10
      """.stripMargin).collect().foreach(println)
  }
}
```

My launch command:

```
spark-submit --class "com.hide.etl.region.distribution.HiveTest" --jars /home/workspace/spark-1.2.0-bin-hadoop2/lib_managed/jars/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar,/home/workspace/spark-1.2.0-bin-hadoop2/lib_managed/jars/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar,/home/workspace/spark-1.2.0-bin-hadoop2/lib_managed/jars/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar,/home/workspace/hadoop/spark_external_jars/udf-collection-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar,/home/workspace/hadoop/sqoop/mysql-connector-java-5.1.31.jar --master yarn-cluster --num-executors 16 --driver-memory 8g --executor-memory 4g --executor-cores 4  scala.test.jar
```

I'm sure that the UDF .jar file is loaded correctly and `create function` HQL works without any error by applying the same code to `spark-shell`. The above error is thrown only when `row_to_map` is used.

The HQL works fine in Hive cli. So, could anyone give me some idea about this error? Thanks a lot!

Comment: which version of spark are you using?

Comment: Spark 1.2.0, Scala 2.10.4, Hive 0.13.0, Hadoop 2.2.0 @ShyamendraSolanki

Comment: Have you tried using the context's hql method instead of sql?

Comment: It's the same error. And `HiveContext.hql` is deprecated in Spark 1.2.0. @JustinPihony